# gitlab crowd exist user ; can't find menu Under “Connected Accounts”

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-crowd

I trey  gitlab-ee-11.8 ; gitlab-ce-11.8

new user can login and create account  from crowd to gitlab ; 
but exist user can't.

**Sign-in failed because Email has already been taken**

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html#enable-omniauth-for-an-existing-user

Enable OmniAuth for an Existing User

Existing users can enable OmniAuth for specific providers after the account is created. For example, if the user originally signed in with LDAP, an OmniAuth provider such as Twitter can be enabled. Follow the steps below to enable an OmniAuth provider for an existing user.

```
Sign in normally - whether standard sign in, LDAP, or another OmniAuth provider.
Go to profile settings (the silhouette icon in the top right corner).
Select the “Account” tab.
***Under “Connected Accounts” select the desired OmniAuth provider, such as Twitter.**    where ? I can't find!!!*
The user will be redirected to the provider. Once the user authorized GitLab they will be redirected back to GitLab.
```

Answer (score 0):

follow  code 
button_based_providers

crowd is form_based_providers

so  only   twitter   will  have "Connected Accounts"  menu

crowd  not support it !